# Enable joystick instead of touchpad in Xonotic

Tags: touchpad, games, gamepad

When playing `Xonotic` the joystick `Logitech F310` was already working
but after restarting computer it stopped completely work.

When I press `shift`+`esc` during the game I try to enable the joystick
with

`joy_enable 1`

but it seems to enable my touchpad instead of joystick.

It writes:

`Joystick 0 opened (SDL_Joystick 0 is "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" ...`

The game starts to rotate and no joystick buttons are working.

How to correct it, so that
`joy_enable 1` it will enable my joystick?

Joystick is seen in `jstest-gtk` as `/dev/input/js0`

I also set the variable

`export SDL_JOYSTICK_DEVICE=/dev/input/js0`

`sudo chmod 777 /dev/input/js0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like SDL is mistakenly identifying your touchpad as a joystick. This seems weird but makes a little sense if you understand that joystick inputs and touchpad inputs look similar. They both send inputs as a pair of absolute X and Y coordinates, and they both have buttons.

Probably SDL sees your F310 gamepad as well, but enumerates the devices in a different order depending on things like whether the gamepad was connected when the game was launched. You can tell xonotic to use the second gamepad by running `joy_index 1` in the in-game console.